# How to boost the search text results using solr?

Tags: solr

I am using solr search but in this i have an issue of boosting my results. I have three fields named Title, Summary and body. If i searched on title , sorting order of results are correct but if i search on summary or body it will not reflect the right results . So can anybody please help me with this.

I used debug log also. but unable to find the issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Whats your configuration ? how are you querying ?

You can use the [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) query handler and define a new request handler in your solrconfig.xml.
Boost the qf fields accordingly as in e.g. below matches on title are higher than summary and matches on summary is higher than body.
In addition you can use [phrase boosts](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#pf_.28Phrase_Fields.29) as well.

```
<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="qf">
      title^1 summary^0.8 body^0.6
   </str>
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="rows">10</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

In addition, you can use [boost query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29) and [boost functions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29) to provide boosts.